# Get puppet build to fail when the contained SQL script fails execution

Tags: sql, oracle, puppet

I am attempting to run a vagrant build which installs Oracle XE in an Ubuntu Virtualbox VM and then runs an SQL script to initialize the Oracle Schema.

The vagrant build is here : https://github.com/ajorpheus/vagrant-ubuntu-oracle-xe
The [setup.sql](https://github.com/ajorpheus/vagrant-ubuntu-oracle-xe/blob/master/modules/oracle/files/setup.sql) is run as a part of the oracle module's [init.pp](https://github.com/ajorpheus/vagrant-ubuntu-oracle-xe/blob/master/modules/oracle/manifests/init.pp) (look near the end of that file or search for 'oracle-script').

I was getting an error while running this vagrant build and was just being told that the 'oracle-script' bit was not successful without any more details. To figure out whether it is a problem with the 'oracle-script' bit, I extracted it out into a [test-sql.pp](https://github.com/ajorpheus/vagrant-ubuntu-oracle-xe/blob/master/test_sql.pp) :

```
file {
    '/tmp/setup.sql':
      ensure => file,
      source => '/tmp/setup.sql';
  }

  exec { 'oracle-script':
    path => ['/bin', '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin'],
    command => 'sqlplus system/manager@xe < /tmp/setup.sql',
    require => [ File['/tmp/setup.sql']],
    timeout => '0',
  }
```

Now I have another issue (which is what this question is about). The setup.sql creates a table space and on subsequent runs, the tablespace creation should fail and so should the puppet script.

I am running the following command

```
puppet apply --verbose --debug test-sql.pp
```

And the output always indicates a successful outcome:

```
debug: Exec[oracle-script](provider=posix): Executing 'sqlplus system/manager@xe < /tmp/setup.sql'
debug: Executing 'sqlplus system/manager@xe < /tmp/setup.sql'
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: executed successfully
```

However, if I run the same SQL script manually:
[image]

---

**Questions**

1. Why doesn't the Puppet build fail even though the contained SQL script does? Should I be looking at the exit codes of SQL Plus?
2. How can I get puppet to emit more verbose debug information? I found [this](http://www.devco.net/archives/2009/08/19/tips_and_tricks_for_puppet_debugging.php), and have tried the suggestions there.
3. After RTFM ... I see that Puppet's [exec](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec) is required to be idempotent. However, the question remains, if the tablespace already exists, why doesn't the puppet build fail?

Thanks!

**Update**

After adding logoutput, as per TheQ's suggestion below, I see the following output:

```
debug: Executing 'sqlplus system/manager@xe < /tmp/setup.sql'
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns:
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sat Apr 5 16:02:37 2014
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns:
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns:
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns:
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: Connected to:
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns:
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: create tablespace some_INDEX_50M datafile '~\u01\some_INDEX_50M.dbf' size 50m
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: *
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: ERROR at line 1:
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: ORA-01543: tablespace 'SOME_INDEX_50M' already exists
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns:
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns:
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[oracle-script]/returns: executed successfully
```

Comment: According to debug output, sqlplus seems to return "executed successfully" even though there was an error. The problem here is with sqlplus reporting success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe puppet detects the success of the script based on the return code of the called program. By default, sqlplus returns 0 when you close it, regardless of what may have been ran during the session.

```
[oracle@bbdb2 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Apr 17 08:47:08 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select asdjkhasd from sadbjaksd;
select asdjkhasd from sadbjaksd
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> quit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
[oracle@bbdb2 ~]$ echo $?
0
```

If you want sqlplus to exit with an error status, you can use the whenever command, e.g.

```
[oracle@bbdb2 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Thu Apr 17 08:48:17 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> whenever sqlerror exit failure;
SQL> select bogus from nowhere;
select bogus from nowhere
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
[oracle@bbdb2 ~]$ echo $?
1
```

Notice the different return code in the latter case. This should be enough to let puppet know the command failed.

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer all part of the question, but if you use [logoutput](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-logoutput), you should see a lot more output from the exec command. By default the output appears only if exec detects a failure, which does not seem to be happening in your case.

Therefore, regarding #2 try adding:

```
logoutput => 'true',
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I can now see the script failing (the build is still not failing), but this is most helpful. (Note to self: RTFM). Cheers!

Comment: I am marking this as the accepted answer, since it led me to diagnose and fix the root cause of the issue (namely, environment variables not being set)