# Is there a better way than this to run an SQL script through puppet?

Tags: sql, oracle, puppet

Take a look at [Get puppet build to fail when the contained SQL script fails execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885941/get-puppet-build-to-fail-when-the-contained-sql-script-fails-execution)

I was attempting to run a vagrant build which installs Oracle XE in an Ubuntu Virtualbox VM and then runs a an SQL script to initialize the Oracle Schema. The vagrant build is here : https://github.com/ajorpheus/vagrant-ubuntu-oracle-xe. The [setup.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22886057/325742) is run as a part of the oracle module's [init.pp](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-logoutput) (right at the bottom or search for 'oracle-script').

When running the SQL script as a part of the vagrant build, I see the following error:

```
notice: /Stage[main]/Oracle::Xe/Exec[oracle-script]/returns: Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
notice: /Stage[main]/Oracle::Xe/Exec[oracle-script]/returns: SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
notice: /Stage[main]/Oracle::Xe/Exec[oracle-script]/returns: SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

There were two things that were instrumental in me finding a workaround for the problem:

1. As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22886057/325742) answer, setting the [logoutput](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-logoutput) attribute to true for the exec block under question immediately showed me the error, whereas before the exec was just failing silently.
2. It seemed strange that I was able to run the command (`sqlplus system/manager@xe < /tmp/setup.sql`) after manually logging in as the 'vagrant' user. That suggested that there was something missing in the environment. Therefore, I copied all ORACLE env. vars into the exec as seen on Line 211 [here](https://github.com/ajorpheus/vagrant-ubuntu-oracle-xe/commit/c9416c0023b41b53084a233d70b655e1b6acf349)

That worked, however, setting up the env vars manually seems a bit brittle. Is there a better way to setup the ORACLE environment for the vagrant user? Or, is there a way to get puppet to setup the environment for the vagrant user similar to an interactive shell?

Answer (score 0):

If some profile has been set up to give the user a working interactive shell, you should be able to pass your action through such a shell

```
command => 'bash -i -c "<actual command>"'
```

As an aside about logoutput, since you mentioned that - the [documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-logoutput) advises that "on_failure" is a sane default, as it will only bloat your output when there are actual errors to analyze. It is the actual default in the latests versions of Puppet.